# Kendo mvc command custom doesnt working

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I got in kendo grid command.custom which is sending data to controller by javascript, but it doesn't working. There's no effect if I click the button. I used almost the same code on another grid and there is no problem. My command.custom:

```
columns.Command(
  command =>
    {
      command
       .Custom(T("ActivityLogger.ActivityCategory.ActivityCategoryList"))
       .Click("activityCategoryList");
    })
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
function activityCategoryList(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    window.location.href = 
      '@Url.Action("ActivityCategoryList", "Activity")' + 
      "?categoryId=" + 
      dataItem.Id;
}
```

I tried to debug this script but it's not even run the javascript. Don't have idea what is wrong

Comment: What is T("ActivityLogger.ActivityCategory.ActivityCategoryList")? Does it return a string?

Comment: Yep, it's dictionary. I changed it to normal string and it's working, but it's weird because I used dictionary on another grid and there is everything fine. I really hate kendo